# Binding SQL table to DataGridView in WPF

Tags: sql, wpf, data-binding, datagridview

How can I bound SQL table to datagridview in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're referring to the `DataGrid` object (?), but [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx) should have all the information you need on it.

Answer (score 0):

We can not use this DataGridView directly. To use this we have to add two references named as:

System.Windows.Forms (Refers to the controls we are building a wrapper for)
WindowsFormsIntegration (which holds the WindowsFormsHost control we'll use)